# Ordering items with known pair distances

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

There are a number of items (lets say a,b,c,d,e) where the relative distances between subsets of them is known. The size of the subsets is limited, though I'd like to receive a final ordering of all items with scores. As example:

```
a,b,c
1,3,5

c,d,e
4,1,10
```

Should lead to something like

```
a,d,b,c,e
```

The real implementation will be quite a bit larger (about 5.000 subsets of 5 items each) so I'm trying to find an algorithm that can do this efficiently. Are there any known solutions to solve a problem like this (no code required, a conceptual idea will be more then helpful)?

Comment: You are getting downvoted because your question just asks us to write the code for you. You need to include what have you tried, where did it fail etc. Please see [ask].

Comment: what is your data type? what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After (rightfully) being downvoted for not posting a solution I came up with the following:

```
sets = [
    [["a", 1], ["b", 5], ["c", 9]],
    [["c", 3], ["d", 1], ["e", 5]]
]
pairs = {}
for set in sets:
    processed_pairs = []
    for first in set:
        for second in set:
            if first[0] is second[0]:
                continue

            pair = first[0]+second[0]
            if pair in processed_pairs:
                continue
            processed_pairs.append(pair)
            if second[0] not in pairs:
                pairs[second[0]] = {}
            if first[0] not in pairs[second[0]]:
                pairs[second[0]][first[0]] = {}
            pairs[second[0]][first[0]] = second[1]/first[1]
pairs
```

Resulting in these pairs:

```
{'a': {'b': 0.2, 'c': 0.1111111111111111},
 'b': {'a': 5.0, 'c': 0.5555555555555556},
 'c': {'a': 9.0, 'b': 1.8, 'd': 3.0, 'e': 0.6},
 'd': {'c': 0.3333333333333333, 'e': 0.2},
 'e': {'c': 1.6666666666666667, 'd': 5.0}}

values = {"a": 1}
for i in ['b', 'c', 'd', 'e']:
    for letter in pairs[i]:
        if letter in values:
            values[i] = values[letter]*pairs[i][letter] 
values
```

Resulting in:

```
{'a': 1, 'b': 5.0, 'c': 9.0, 'd': 3.0, 'e': 15.0}
```

Which is not the prettiest, but acceptable.